# Passing dynamic data from app module to another module in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am getting dynamic data from router events (to go get history from RoutesRecognized) in app.componant! I have created a another module in app module. I want to share this data everytime that module is loaded.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
            .pairwise()
            .subscribe((e: any) => {
                this.printParent(e);
            });
    }

    printParent(item: any) {
        console.log(item[0].url);
        console.log(item[1].url);
    }
}
```

I want to pass item[0].url everytime that module is loaded

Comment: Check this link: http://www.codershood.info/2016/10/09/passing-data-angular-2-components/

Comment: Your question doesn't read correctly."I am getting dynamic data from router events go get history from RoutesRecognized in app.componant! I" Huh?

Comment: @sirandy the componant i want to pass that data is inside a module! this module i have defined inside app module. what you suggested will work here?

--app module
|__ aboutmodule
     |__about componant

I want to pass data from app componat to about componant

Comment: @JGFMK is it easy to understand now! please forgive my English! I am not very good with it!